# How to use **kwarg in Dart (like in Python)

Tags: dart

I have a question on how to easily use map as a parameter in Dart. Is there any easy way of passing all the key-values pairs of a map object to a function?

For example, I have a map and a function like this:

```dart
const testMap = {"a": 1, "b":2};

int testFunc(a, b){
  return a + b;
}
```

and I want to use them like this:

```dart
testFunct(**testMap) // not possible in dart (though possible in python)
```

which should give us `3` as the result.

Any smart solution like this? Thanks!

---

Please note that ** is the python-way of passing the parameters inside dictionary: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not directly possible the way you write it, but you can do something similar using `Function.apply`.

You have to either pass the arguments as positional, and then you need to know the order:

```dart
const testMap = {"a": 1, "b":2};

int testFunc(a, b){
  return a + b;
}

void main() {
  print(Function.apply(testFunc, testMap.values.toList()));
}
```

or you have to use named *parameters* and then the map keys should be symbols:

```dart
const testMap = {#a: 1, #b:2};

int testFunc({required int a, required int b}){
  return a + b;
}

void main() {
  print(Function.apply(testFunc, [], testMap));
}
```

Dart distinguishes positional and named parameters, so if you want to refer to a parameter by name, it should be named.

The former approach is dangerous because you don't use the names of the map. It should really just be `const testArguments = [1, 2];` and not include a map which doesn't help you.

Using `Function.apply` is not type safe. It's as type-safe as calling something with type `dynamic` or `Function` — which means not safe at all — so use it carefully and only when necessary.

Comment: Great answer! 

By the way, this might be a little off topic, but what's the role of sharp-mark (#)? Is it an abbrivation of double-quotated string? I've searched dart docs but couldn't find it easily. Thanks!

Comment: A *symbol literal* like `#foo` is a way to create a `Symbol` object representing the source name `foo`. It's a special kind of object used by the run-time system to represent source names, in `Function.apply`, in the `Invocation` provided to `noSuchMethod` and in `dart:mirrors` in general. Using a `Symbol` instead of a `String` to hold the name allows web-compilers to rename variables to shorter names (minimization) to reduce the download size of the program, without breaking `Function.apply` and `noSuchMethod`. `#foo` is the same as `const Symbol("foo")`.